# Added antiword buildpack in heroku but getting error

Tags: heroku, npm, antiword

I am trying to fetch the doc file text using "textract" npm module but for this I have to install one of its dependency "antiword" on heroku

The command I used to install it was:

```
 heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/ropensci/antiword.git
```

But antiword is throwing error at the time of extracting text from doc file

```
error is Error: antiword read of file named [[ 1619419536356test.doc ]] failed: Error: Command failed: antiword -m UTF-8.txt "/app/public/user_files/1619419536356test.doc"
2021-04-26T06:45:38.048275+00:00 app[web.1]: I can't open your mapping file (UTF-8.txt)
2021-04-26T06:45:38.048276+00:00 app[web.1]: It is not in '/app/.antiword' nor in '/usr/share/antiword'.
2021-04-26T06:45:38.048277+00:00 app[web.1]: Name: antiword
```

Answer (score 0):

Antiword is trying to find specific files in `/app/.antiword` which happens to be the location of your repo. I ended up just manually adding those files.

1. At the root directory of your repo, add a folder named `.antiword`
2. From the [Antiword Repo](https://github.com/rsdoiel/antiword), download the contents of the `Resources` folder and move them into your `.antiword` folder
3. Commit and push your repo to Heroku with the new folder